# How can I redirect a request to the site root using htaccess, if there's not a specific cookie set?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, language

I'm using this code, versions of which I've seen referenced on various other sites, but it always redirects home page requests to /fr/ if the browser is set with French as a primary language preference.

I only want to redirect root domain requests (/) if the cookie “language_known” isn't set to the value “yes”.

Does anyone have any ideas, please?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Redirect if French browser
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !language_known=true;? [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the cookie “language_known” isn't set to the value “yes”.
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !language_known=true;? [NC]
> ```

The *condition* is checking that the value is not "true" (string), not "yes"?

However, the rule is also configured as a 301 (permanent) redirect, so this will be cached persistently by the browser. If the browser has redirected once, when the cookie was not set then it will *always* be redirected, even when the cookie is later set (since the request never reaches the server to perform the check).

This *needs* to be a 302 (temporary) redirect so the browser does not cache the redirect (by default). And the browser (and any intermediary) cache needs to be cleared before this can be tested.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! The code example was incorrect - I was checking for !language_known=yes - but clearing the browser cache and using a 302 did the trick. Thanks!